# meaning in context question

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> It also appears to caution that the strong cultural emphasis in the US on individual **drive and success** that makes retaining a sense of homeland tradition difficult should be identified and responded to in ways that allow for a healthy new sense of identity to be formed.

I can understand the sentence without "drive and success", but when it is included, it makes me hard to understand it. Is "drive" and "success" used as noun or verb in this sentence?

Comment: They are nouns--*success* is always a noun, and the conjunction of *drive* with it marks *drive* as a noun too.

Comment: Please read [this meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source); it explains why we'd like for you to tell us where you found a sentence like this.

Comment: The sentence wouldn't actually make any sense without *drive and success*.  Reading "...the strong cultural emphasis in the US on individual makes retaining..." would make me say "On individual *what*?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misinterpreted this phrase.  Actually these are two separate nouns both modified by "individual":

> ... the strong cultural emphasis in the US on **individual drive** and **individual success**, that makes ...

In other words, US culture emphasizes two things (and this emphasis has other effects).

Otherwise it's kind of a [run-on sentence](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/runons.htm), and difficult to parse in places, but not unusually so.